# Find area of one leaf of a four-petaled rose, than prove that the total area of the rose is 1/2 the circumference of the circle

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

Find the area of one leaf of the "four-petaled rose" $r=\sin 2\theta$. Then prove that the total area of the rose is equal to one-half the area of the circumscribed circle.

[image: maths!]

Hey friends, just a quick math problem that stumped me during my homework.

So, I was able to find that one rose has area $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin2\theta)^2d\theta$$ or that all four roses have area $$2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin2\theta)^2d\theta$$

However, I am not sure how to start the proving of the area? My inital thoughts involve $\pi r^2$ for the area? But I am not positive how that would phase. How could I approach this problem, and what would be the logical solution?

Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To compute the integral, use the fact that $\sin^2(x)=\dfrac{1-\cos2x}{2}$.